# PHP: Set the value of a multidimensional associative array element using a path defined in a separate array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Ok so I have an array that holds the following elements:

```
$array['a']['b'][0]['c'];
$array['a']['b'][1]['c'];
$array['a']['d'][0]['c']['c'];
$array['b']['c'];
```

Then in a separate array, I have defined the path to these values:

```
$structure[0] = array('a','b','#','c');
$structure[1] = array('a','d','#','c','c');
$structure[2] = array('b','c');
```

Finally, I have an array holding the values:

```
$values[0] = array('value0-0','value0-1');
$values[1] = array('value1-0');
$values[2] = array('value2-0');
```

I'm trying to find a simple function/loop that will be able to apply the values in $values to the array path of $array that is defined in $structure.

The end result would be:

```
$array['a']['b'][0]['c']='value0-0';
$array['a']['b'][1]['c']='value0-1';
$array['a']['d'][0]['c']['c']='value1-0';
$array['b']['c']='value2-0';
```

In the case of $values[0] or $values[1], it would be able to loop through each value and substitute the $structure element matching '#' with the iteration number for that particular $value.

Is this simply a case of knuckling down and writing a drawn out recursive function, or is there a smart construct or php function that could provide a more elegant solution?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Mario, my eventual solution is:

```
foreach ($struct as $i=>$keys)
  foreach ($values[$i] as $val) {
    $r = & $array;

    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        if ($key == "#") { $key = $i; }

        $r = & $r[$key];    // move pointer to subarray
    }

    $r = $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to write some looping.

Comment: A question should never contain its own solution -- that is what "answers" are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to work with references to traverse the target array:

```
function inject($array, $struct, $values) {

    foreach ($struct as $i=>$keys)
    foreach ($values[$i] as $val) {
        $r = & $array;

        foreach ($keys as $key) {

            if ($key == "#") { $key = count($r); }

            settype($r[$key], "array");
            $r = & $r[$key];    // move pointer to subarray
        }

        $r = $val;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

I don't understand the need for `settype()` however, I haven't used it and it doesn't seem to be required. I've posted my final solution in my question.

Comment: @DanH: The `settype` avoids having to test for the existence of the subarrays. It might be redundant in your case, if the target array already contains the corrent (empty) structure. And now that I think of it `& $r[$key]` will actually create missing subarrays. So the `settype` typecast is not necessary.

Comment: Old question but still pertinent.. if you are trying to use the function above, the $array argument should be passed by reference, e.g. &$array, to allow the changes to be returned.