# Ugly editing value on PHP nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON object that I try to modify. So I created the following function. I firstly deserialize the JSON object and then given the array and the path that I want to change I modify the value.

```
function setInDict($arr, $path, $value){
    switch(sizeof($path)){
        case 1:
            $arr[$path[0]] = $value;
            break;
        case 2:
            $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]] = $value;
            break;
        case 3:
            $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]] = $value;
            break;      
        case 4:
            $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]] = $value;
            break;
        case 5:
            $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]][$path[4]] = $value;
            break;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

I tried a lot of things(recursion, &arr) to make it work dynamically but my PHP experience is limited and I cant make it to work.

Is there a clean way to do this. Is there something alternative that I can try?

For example I have the following JSON and I want to modify subsubkey to value 2

```
{  
  "key":{  
    "subkey":{  
      "subsubkey":3
    }
  }
}
```

I deserialize it using `json_decode($json, true);` and I create the `$path` array which would be

```
['key', 'subkey', 'subsubkey']
```

Comment: can you show the input values of `$arr, $path, $value` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Set the value of a multidimensional associative array element using a path defined in a separate array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123061/php-set-the-value-of-a-multidimensional-associative-array-element-using-a-path)

Comment: @MattRaines This is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create new updated array recursively you can use references. The following code walks through the given array and on each iteration changes the reference to the nested array until it reaches the field you want to change.

```
function setInDict(array $array, array $path, $value)
{
    if (!$path) {
        return $array;
    }

    $found = &$array;
    foreach ($path as $field) {
        if (!isset($found[$field]) || !array_key_exists($field, $found)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("There is no nested field '$field' in the given array");
        }

        $found = &$found[$field];
    }

    $found = $value;

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to express but I think I have misused references.

Comment: Can I also delete the key found using this?

Comment: Yes, but the code will be a little bit different. You have to ```unset``` the last key from the path.

Comment: Should be something like this ```if ($isLast) unset($found[$field]); else $found = &$found[$field];```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$x= '{  
  "key":{  
    "subkey":{  
      "subsubkey":3
    },
    "subkeyx":{  
      "subsuwefwef":3
    }
  }
}';

$x = json_decode($x, true);
echo json_encode(checkValue($x,2,"subsubkey"));

function checkValue($x,$y,$keyName){

    if(is_array($x)){
        foreach($x as $key=>$value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $check = checkValue($value,$y,$keyName);
                $x[$key] = $check;
            }elseif($key == $keyName){
                $x[$key] = $y;

            } 

        }
    }

    return $x;

}
```

Output:

```
{"key":{"subkey":{"subsubkey":2},"subkeyx":{"subsuwefwef":3}}}
```

Comment: This will change all keys recursively and not the specified one in the `$path`.

Comment: @YoloQ I edited so it will check for "subsubkey". will that work for you? it won't check the whole path. just the last key in the path.

Comment: See the accepted answer of what I was trying to accomplish.